# Lasso with Categorical Variables

Tags: r, lasso

I am running a lasso model to predict a continuous variable, and I have continuous and categorical inputs.

- In terms of centering and scaling - is it correct that this should only be applied to continuous variables?
- Also, in terms of the dummy variables step, can this be ignored for the categorical? It just doesn't make sense when it comes to scoring.

  - For example, if the training set has a category called Cats, that has levels A-Z, this would create a column for A-Z. But if my scoring set is missing one of these levels then it will fall over.
    Looking for some guidance.

Comment: I mean an independent predictor variable, the target variable is continuous.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ridge\Lasso -- Standardization of dummy indicators](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/359015/ridge-lasso-standardization-of-dummy-indicators) That covers the centering/scaling. [Group lasso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)#Group_lasso) provides a way to handle all levels of a multi-level categorical predictor, although details might depend on your particular data set and purpose for modeling.

Comment: Yes, that kind of helps, thanks!